# YouTube Data API "live" playlists are now empty, have these been deprecated?

Tags: youtube-data-api

The [ChannelSection list API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/list) API request returns the different sections for a channel; ie for The Grand Theft Auto V channel it returned the "live", "recent", "official", etc, sections, which included the `playlistId`. An example of the playlist node in the response for the channel id `UCOquqcRMJmURiGfEnaitptg` is:

```
...
{
    "contentDetails": {
        "playlists": [
            "PLr8KIbGK44Lt1FxvfO1Ea0xYeWTTII1Na"
        ]
    },
    "etag": "QcA2Ykw1DFw_fKjzOJUJw-0nUy4",
    "id": "UCOquqcRMJmURiGfEnaitptg.c_TXvTHqgWc",
    "kind": "youtube#channelSection",
    "snippet": {
        "channelId": "UCOquqcRMJmURiGfEnaitptg",
        "position": 5,
        "title": "Live Worldwide",
        "type": "singleplaylist"
    }
},
...
```

Navigating to this [playlist on the YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLr8KIbGK44Lt1FxvfO1Ea0xYeWTTII1Na) shows no videos in the playlist.

This appears to be the case for lots of other automated "live" playlists. Are these still being updated or have they been deprecated?

Is there a better way through the YouTube APIs to get the current live streams for a specific game? For example find all users currently streaming Fortnite or Grand Theft Auto.